# Proper open subgroup of ($\mathbb{C^{*}}$,.)

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

I know,  there does not exist any proper open subgroup of ($\mathbb{R}$, +) .  My question,  does the result true for ($\mathbb{C^{*}}$,.)  I. e.  Does there exist any proper open subgroup of ($\mathbb{C^{*}}$,.) ?

Comment: Hint: a connected topological group can't have a proper open subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\Bbb C$ does not have proper open subgroups either, because if $G<\Bbb C$ is open, then $G\cap \Bbb R$ and $G\cap i\Bbb R$ are open subgroups of $\Bbb R$ (and $i\Bbb R\cong\Bbb R$) and therefore $G\supseteq \Bbb R+i\Bbb R=\Bbb C$.

If $G<\Bbb C^*$ is open, then $\exp^{-1}[G]=\{z\in\Bbb C\,:\, e^x\in G\}$ is an open subgroup of $\Bbb C$, therefore $\exp^{-1}[G]=\Bbb C$ and $G=\Bbb C^*$.